# Ios :: toolbar alignment issue

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem, xcode6.3.1

i have added toolbar in the xib file. but it doesn't show up correctly in ios6 simulator. it shows up perfect in ios4 simulator.

below  are screenshots.

iphone 6 image

[image: iphone6 image]

Iphone4s image

[image: iphone 4s iamge]

Please look at slide left to delete toolbar in the images, it is fine in iPhone 4s but it comes in between in iPhone 6 simulator.

Please help to fix the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Below piece of code fixed my issue for all the simulators.

```
//Caclulate the height of the toolbar
CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;

//Get the bounds of the parent view
CGRect rootViewBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

//Get the height of the parent view.
CGFloat rootViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rootViewBounds);

//Get the width of the parent view,
CGFloat rootViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rootViewBounds);

//Create a rectangle for the toolbar
CGRect rectArea = CGRectMake(0, rootViewHeight - toolbarHeight, rootViewWidth, toolbarHeight);
self.toolbar.frame = rectArea;
```

i have put above code in viewWillAppear method.